# Javascript String Deobfuscation on prompt

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

I'm trying to create a simple tool to dump out a string that was obfuscated.

obfuscated string sample: op\u0065\u006E

normally, i do`prompt("","copy paste string");`

but it's getting repetitive.

so i tried this:

```
loop:
while(true){
    var string_code = prompt("CHECK: "); 
    switch (string_code) {
        case "lol": 
            break loop;
        default: 
        prompt("answer",string_code);
    }
}
```

but i found that it doesn't process the string like before,

and just dumps what the user inputted, literally.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where/how were you processing the string at all in before?

Comment: Where is the code that used to work?

Comment: original code was just this => prompt("","copy paste string"); 

then I compile again for another obfuscated string. It was THAT tedious.